# My JavaScript won't repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

The following snippet is my jQuery for a slider however it's stopping on the last image and not cycling through to the first again. Any ideas?

```
function cycleImages() {
var $active = $('#cycler .active');
var $next = ($active.next().length>0) ? $active.next():$('cycler img:first');
$next.css('z-index', 2);
$active.fadeOut(1500, function () {
    $active.css('z-index', 1).show().removeClass('active');
    $next.css('z-index', 5).addClass('active');

});
}

    $(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval('cycleImages()', 4000);
})
```

Comment: It's better not to pass functions as strings to `setInterval` or `eval` - instead you can do `setInterval(cycleImages, 4000)`

Comment: `$('cycler` probably should be `$('#cycler`

Comment: @PatrickEvans that seems to be it - voting to close as typo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just giving the code a passing glance, I believe that your problem is in the if statement. Your `$('cycler img:first')` should have a hashtag as such: `$('#cycler img:first')`